# componentDidUpdate not being called

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a react native app, and I am calling componentDidUpdate on App.js, but it doesn't fire.
I wonder if this is because I am calling from App.js?
Here is the App.js files:

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        if (this.props.text && this.props.text.toString().trim()) {
            Alert.alert(this.props.title || 'Mensagem', this.props.text.toString());
            this.props.clearMessage();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Navigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ message }) => {
    return {
        title: message.title,
        text: message.text
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        clearMessage: () => dispatch(setMessage({
            title: '',
            text: ''
        }))
    }
}

const connectDispatch = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
const connectApp = connectDispatch(App);

export default connectApp;
```

And here is where I am calling it.Inside a dispatch in posts action.

```
    .then(res => {
        dispatch(fetchPosts());
        dispatch(postCreated());
        dispatch(setMessage({
            title: 'Sucesso',
            text: 'Nova Postagem!'
        }));
    });
```

All other dispatchs are fired.
It's not the if that is preventing the alert to be fired, because I already put the alert outside of the if.

Comment: I can fix it if you share a snack of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
componentDidUpdate = () => { ... }
```

for this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) { ... }
```

Keep in mind the componentDidUpdate does not trigger on first render

Comment: Try doing two console.log() inside the componentDidUpdate function. One inside if and one outside. Check if the one outside si entering. If it is, then the problem should be on your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!

I could fix it.

Instead of importing from '.ActionTypes' I was importing from 'Message'

import { SET_MESSAGE } from '../actions/ActionTypes';

I am new to Redux and it caught me offguard!